# Zend_Dojo_Form_Element creating simple elements  ("acting" as Zend_Form_Element)

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo, dijit.form

I'm trying to create a dijit button in ZF. I've tried using plain dojo and it works, but when using Zend_Dojo it creates a simple button, in other words, Zend_Dojo_Form_Elements acts as Zend_Form_Element.

**IndexController** without Zend_Dojo (this way the button is render properly):

```
$newEventButton = new Zend_Form_Element_Button('newEvent', array('dijitType'=>'dijit.form.Button');
$newEventButton->setLabel('New Event'); 
$this->view->newEventButton = $newEventButton;
```

**IndexController** with Zend_Dojo (this way it creates a simple button as it can be seen bellow):

```
$newEventButton = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_Button('newEvent');
$newEventButton->setLabel('New Event'); 
$this->view->newEventButton = $newEventButton;
```

And the result is:

```
enter code here
<button type="button" id="newEvent" name="newEvent">New event</button>
```

What am I doing wrong, why the Zend_Dojo_Form_Element acts as Zend_Form_Element? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to create a button, directly use a view helper (Zend_Dojo_View_Helper_Button) instead of using a form element (Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_Button). Before doing this, make sure you include the dojo view helpers in your bootstrap:

```
$view->addHelperPath(
    'Zend/Dojo/View/Helper/',
    'Zend_Dojo_View_Helper'
);
```

And make sure you enable Dojo view helper in your view or layout:

```
$view->dojo()->enable();
```

Now, to directly use the view helper (Zend_Dojo_View_Helper_Button) to render your button (bypassing Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_Button, which you should use only when building a complete form). In your view:

```
echo $this->button('newEvent', null, array('label' => 'New Event', 'onclick' => 'someAction()'));
```

Or if you want to define the button in the controller:

```
$this->view->newEventButton = $this->view->button('newEvent', null, array('label' => 'New Event', 'onclick' => 'someAction()'));
```

And then render it in the view:

```
echo $this->newEventButton;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have the view helpers included in my bootstrap and also I have enabled Dojo in the layout, that's way using the first method described in my question, the button is rendered as a dijit button. I have tried you're method too. Still no result. I really need to make it work because at some point I will use a Zend_Dojo_Form and i need it to be created as a dijit.form.Form type, not a simple form.

Comment: No errors, everything seems ok. Now I saw your edit about the Zend_Dojo_View_Helper_Button. I didn't knew about it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yes, the initial post could have been confusing, so I explicitly differentiated the View Helper from the Form Element; the latter uses the former to render a button using a Decorator (ViewHelper Decorator for plain form elements AND Dijit Decorator for dojo form elements); however, Form Element classes are only really useful in the context of complete forms; if you just want a button or a displaced form element, it's easier to directly use view helpers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the parseOnLoad configuration variable when loading dojo?

```
<script> djConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}; </script>
<script src="path to dojo"></script>
```

Comment: Yes. Anyway, I also used your method and still nothing :(

Comment: Well, can you create your widgets programatically (within Javascript) at least?

Comment: I could try, but it's not something i want; I have a huge amount of js already.

Comment: Then see if you can have your widgets render by manually calling dojo.parser.parse( the_root_dom_node_to_convert )  -- dojo.require('dojo.parser') first, ofc

Comment: the_root_dom_node_to_convert = the id or the object. I don't think I understand what I have to do...

Comment: Dojo should handle any of them just fine (due to dojo.byId)

Comment: It does not see it as a dojo element (in order to select it with dojo.byId). Anyway, it should work with Zend_Dojo. I will try something else. Thank you for your help.